# How can I define (user defined) functions in math mode?

Tags: math-operators

I am used to define some complicated and frequent mathematical expressions to be able to use them easily in my papers. For example I have defined 
`\def\c{{\mathbb{C}}}` for `$\mathbb{C}$` (the field of complex numbers).

However sometimes there are more complicated formulas and mathematical expressions which involve one, two, or more variables (or parameters). For example, consider `$Hom_{\mathbb{Z}} (M,N)$` which involves two variables `$M$` and `$N$`.

My question is "how can I define such expressions generally with the ability to change the variable inside them.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define macros with parameters? For example `\Homz{M}{N}` to give this output?

Comment: Yes something like that. How is it possible?

Comment: A suggestion: don't use `\c` for some command (for example, complex numbers). I'm warning because it happened to me. I got a file with this personal command used a lot of times and I was not able to use the `\c c` to produce `ç`. So some find/replace was necessary.

Comment: A colleague of mine used to have `\def\a{\alpha}` `\def\b{\beta}` `\def\c{\gamma}`. One day he wrote me because of a mysterious error; his coauthor for a paper was Turkish and his family name began with Ş. Well, he could type the name directly in UTF-8, but the problem is that LaTeX translates this into `\c{S}`. Chaos ensues. Don't use `\def`, unless you know precisely what you're doing, after having carefully checked what a command we proceed to redefine does.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are not variables in "typesetting sense". You *could* define

```
\newcommand{\Hom}[3]{\operatorname{Hom}_{#1}(#2,#3)}
```

and then use

```
\Hom{Z}{M}{N}
```

for getting

> Hom<sub>*Z*</sub>(*M*, *N*)

but this is no way more expressive or readable than

```
\Hom_{Z}(M,N)
```

after having defined

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
```

Actually, I contend that the latter form is *much* more readable than the first one.

---

Note. Be careful in saying

```
\def\c{\mathbb{C}}
```

because `\c` is an "accent command" in LaTeX (`\c{c}` is used in French, Albanian, Turkish, Portuguese, Catalan and other languages). Always use `\newcommand` or, if you really know what you're doing, `\renewcommand`; but don't redefine general use commands: if one of your bibliography items contains a "ç" you'll regret having redefined `\c`.

Comment: I had that problem with `ç`. See my comment above... lol

Comment: @egreg: Thank you. It is exactly what I was looking for. It may seem less readable, but it will help me in writing papers.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh I don't think so. I tell you because I used that way in my first experiences with TeX/LaTeX and changed my mind after seeing that it *doesn't* shorten the typing nor it makes the input more readable.

Answer (score 5):

On the preamble, use

```
\DeclareMathOperator{command}{text}
```

to define math operators. For example, you can use

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
```

to define the command `\Hom`, and use it as `$\Hom_Z(M,N)$`. Compare with `$Hom_Z(M,N)$`.

[image]

Now, if you want to insert the modules as variables, you can define a new command and pass them like you do with `\frac{}{}`, for example.

```
\newcommand{\myhom}[2]{\Hom_Z(#1,#2)}
```

So you can format any variable globally just formating the `#1`, for example.

Comment: Could you give an example how it works? How should I introduce the variables?

Comment: Thanks Sigur. But it does not look that much easier. I am looking for a way to define the whole bifunctor Hom with the ability to use different modules M and N whenever I needed.

Comment: But it is the same: type `\Hom(M,N)` with `()` or `\Hom{}{}` with `{}` 2 times takes almost the same time. I believe that the right way is to use it as operator, to format the font shape. But arguments to it, I think irrelevant.

Comment: I just tried `\newcommand{\Hom}[3]{\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{#1}}(#2,#3)}` and it works perfectly. I am sure it will help me to save time in writing repeated formulas with different variables.