# Render text upright in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I am looking for a way to have LaTeX render strings *of more than one letter* as upright (in math mode).  For example, I want it to render

- `$Hom$` as `$\mathrm{Hom}$`,
- `$apple$` as `$\mathrm{apple}$`,
- `$apple + orange$` as `$\mathrm{apple} + \mathrm{orange}$`,

while rendering

- `$a$` and `$a + o$` as normal.

The answers at [Use \mathrm by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15058/use-mathrm-by-default) are close to what I want, but they fail the last example.

Comment: don't do this:-) better to declare \Hom as a math operatpr and use like \log and \sin

Comment: See [How can I define (user defined) functions in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95171/5764)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have an unusual use case in mind (rendering math on a web-based wiki), where for practical purposes this would be very useful.

Comment: @Werner, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: As the interletter spacing is not quite the same as ordinary text, you could try simply \textrm{string}.

Comment: If others will contribute to the wiki, there seems to be an even stronger case against it since you cannot expect users to be careful of your short-cuts. That is, isn't there even *more* need for robustness in that case?

Comment: @cfr, there is nothing to be careful about, in the sense that these "shortcuts" (which probably should actually be the default behaviour of LaTeX) do not break anything.

Comment: Really? $(x + y/2)(y/2 + x) = x^2 + y^2/4 + xy$ should render the final term in upright by default?

Comment: @cfr, that should be written as $x y$.

Comment: Kopka and Daly write `xy`. Is that wrong or deprecated? I don't know about maths, but it would be extremely awkward to write that in first order predicate calculus, for example. `$Pxyz$` makes a lot more sense semantically than `$P x y z$`.

Comment: If this is for the web, do you need a mathjax solution (which is off topic actually) of a tex one (which would be unlikely to work with mathjax?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm looking for a TeX solution.

Comment: shame, it would be easier in mathjax as you could use a regular expression replace to add the markup on the fly:-) It's no doubt possible in tex but it's so far against TeX's normal working it would be like breqn and work in isolation but be incompatible with more or less everything, the entire tex math mode layout is built on the idea that white space in the source is ignored and you want to make it affect font choice.

Comment: [Heiko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129454/21344) at the proposed duplicate answers this question.